SFML - C++ : Cuando el objeto "x" detecte colision con objeto "y" no traspase al obstaculo "y"
Necesito ayuda con respecto a las colisiones en SFML para hacer un videojuego
Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el objeto "x" (en este caso un circulo) llegue a colisionar con alguna esquina(o borde) del objeto "y" (en este caso un rectángulo)  el objeto x no lo pueda traspasar, simplemente no se como hacerlo, este es el código.
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML works!");
window.setFramerateLimit(60);

///CIRCULO
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
shape.setRadius(20);
shape.setPosition(500, 400);

///RECTANGULO
sf::RectangleShape _rectangulo;
_rectangulo.setPosition(400, 300);
_rectangulo.setSize({ 100,30 });
sf::RectangleShape& getDraw();

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    ///MOVER PERSONAJE
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
       shape.move(0, -3);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {

        shape.move(-3, 0);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {

        shape.move(3, 0);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {

        shape.move(0, 3);
    }


    ///COLISION


    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.draw(_rectangulo);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}

Lo que hace es dibujar un circulo que permite moverse, y un rectángulo.
Desde ya muchas gracias!
La version de SFML es 2.6.1 programado desde Visual Studio.

Hola Franco, bienvenido, pregunta, uno de los dos está fijo, o ambos se mueven, si uno está fijo, cual es?.

Qué intentaste? SFML tiene motor de colisiones? Si la respuesta es si, será más fácil. Si la respuesta es no, necesitaras un tutorial para saber cómo crear un sistema de físicas. Te dejo un tutorial https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSlpr6o9vURwq3oxVZSimY8iC-cdd3kIs

El circulo(shape) es el que se mueve, el rectagulo esta fijo

La verdad no sabría decir si SFML tiene motor de colisiones, pero voy a ver tu tutorial, gracias!

el código, tiene que ser revisado, porque recién empiezo con C++, y tengo miedo de equivocarme.
El ejemplo que te voy a dar, es basado en clases, algo absolutamente recomendado para juegos, si no te parece bién, lo podés adaptar.
Básicamente usamos dos comprobaciones, una para detectar si el cuadrado que contiene al círculo, está superpuesto con el rectángulo, y otra (si la anterior es cierta) para detectar si el círculo está encimado con el rectángulo. Esto lo hacemos así, porque la primera es "liviana" (en términos de perfomance), y la segunda es "pesada", ya que usamos raices cuadradas.

    boolean detectaChoque( Rec objA, Cir objB ) {
       if( objA.getXX() + objA.getAncho() > objB.getXX()
               && objA.getXX() < objB.getXX() + objB.getAncho()
               && objA.getYY() < objB.getYY() + objB.getAlto()
               && objA.getYY() + objA.getAlto() > objB.getYY() ) {
    
          if( objB.getDireccion().equals( "derecha" ) ) {
             if( objB.getCentroY() < objA.getY() + objA.getAlto()
                     && objB.getCentroY() > objA.getY() ) {
                return true;
             }
             else {
                if( objB.getCentroY() < objA.getYY() ) {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objA.getYY() - objB.getCentroY(),
                           objA.getXX() - objB.getCentroX(), objB );
                }
                else {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objA.getXX() - objB.getCentroX(),
                           objB.getCentroY() - objA.getYY() - objA.getAlto(), objB );
                }
             }
          }
          else if( objB.getDireccion().equals( "izquierda" ) ) {
             if( objB.getCentroY() < objA.getY() + objA.getAlto()
                     && objB.getCentroY() > objA.getY() ) {
                return true;
             }
             else {
                if( objB.getCentroY() < objA.getYY() ) {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objA.getYY()
                           - objB.getCentroY(),
                           objA.getXX()
                           - objB.getCentroX(), objB );
                }
                else {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objB.getCentroY() - objA.getYY() - objA.getAlto(),
                           objB.getCentroX() - objA.getXX() - objA.getAncho(), objB );
                }
             }
          }
          else if( objB.getDireccion().equals( "arriba" ) ) {
             if( objB.getCentroX() < objA.getX() + objA.getAncho()
                     && objB.getCentroX() > objA.getX() ) {
                return true;
             }
             else {
                if( objB.getCentroX() > objA.getXX() + objB.getRadio() ) {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objB.getCentroY() - objA.getYY() - objA.getAlto(),
                           objB.getCentroX() - objA.getXX() - objA.getAncho(), objB );
                }
                else {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objB.getCentroY() - objA.getYY() - objA.getAlto(),
                           objA.getXX() - objB.getCentroX(), objB );
                }
             }
          }
          else if( objB.getDireccion().equals( "abajo" ) ) {
             if( objB.getCentroX() < objA.getX() + objA.getAncho()
                     && objB.getCentroX() > objA.getX() ) {
                return true;
             }
             else {
                if( objB.getCentroX() < objA.getXX() ) {
                   System.out.println( "wa" );
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objA.getYY() - objB.getCentroY(),
                           objA.getXX() - objB.getCentroX(), objB );
                }
                else {
                   return detectaColisionCirculo(
                           objB.getCentroY() - objA.getYY() - objA.getAlto(),
                           objA.getXX() - objB.getCentroX(), objB );
                }
             }
          }
       }
       return false;
    }

     
    boolean distanciaEntrePuntos( int ladoA, int ladoB, Circulo objB ) { 
        return sqrt( ladoA * ladoA + ladoB * ladoB ) < objB.getRadio();
    }

Voy a explicar parcialmente como funciona (para explicarlo bien, necesitaría subir un montón de imágenes, y sería demasido largo).
El primer if detecta que ambos rectángulos esten superpuestos, de no ser así, la función devuelve false.
Acá va un esquema de nuestras figuras, identificando sus esquinas:
A1
-------- A2
A3
-------- A4
B1
-------- B2
B3
-------- B4
(si alguien puede hacerlo mejor, porfi, edite y mejore).
Veamos con una situación, el movil avanza hacia la derecha.
Primero detectamos si el punto "A2" está más a la derecha que "B1", condición necesaria para que esten superpuestos, usamos:
A2 = A.getX() + A.getAncho();
B1 = B.getX();
osea:
if( A.getX() + A.getAncho() > B.getX() 

Luego le agregamos, la verificamos de si "A1" está más a la izquierda que "B2", otra condición necesaria:
A1 = A.getX();
B2 = B.getX() + B.getAncho();
if( A.getX() + A.getAncho() > B.getX() &&
    A.getX() < B.getX() + B.getAncho()

Bien, ya sabemos (si ambos devuelven "true") que en horizontal, están en la misma franja, entonces seguimos con la evaluación vertical, que siguiendo la misma lógica, es:
if( objA.getX() + objA.getAncho() > objB.getX() 
           && objA.getX() < objB.getX() + objB.getAncho()
           && objA.getY() < objB.getY() + objB.getAlto() 
           && objA.getY() + objA.getAlto() > objB.getY() ) {

Ahora, si la sentencia del primer if da "true", entramos en la detección de choque de rectángulo con circulo.
if( objB.getDireccion().equals( "derecha" ) ) {
   if( objB.getCentroY() < objA.getY() + objA.getAlto()
             && objB.getCentroY() > objA.getY() ) {
      return true;
   }

devuelve "true", si el centro del círculo, se encuentra entre "B1" y "B2" del rectángulo, en cuyo hay colisión.
Si no la hay, evaluamos:
if( objB.getCentroY() < objA.getY() ) {

nos devuelve "true", si el centro del círculo, está más a la izquerda de "B1", en cuyo caso, llamamos a distanciaEntrePuntos, con las diferencias entre "Ax" y las "x" del centro del circulo, y "Ay" y las "y" del mismo.
Laas demás comprobaciones, siguen la misma lógica.
Nota:
Para usar la función sqrt deberás incluirla libreria cmath con:
#include<cmath>

Te dejo esta función extra (basada en el primer if):
public boolean rectangulosEncimados( Base objA, Base objB ) {
   if( objA.getX() + objA.getAncho() <= objB.getX()
          || objB.getX() + objB.getAncho() <= objA.getX()
          || objA.getY() + objA.getAlto() <= objB.getY()
          || objB.getY() + objB.getAlto() <= objA.getY() ) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}

PD: en la clase Circulo, debes implementar los métodos getCentroX() y getCentroY() así:
public int getCentroY() {
return Y + radio;
}
public int getCentroX() {
return X + radio;
}
para evitar errores (por falta de actualización).
